# Rendering colored-bar-event with different "accepted state" visually across a number of days

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am building a "leave calendar" where an employee requests time off, and a manager approves it.

If an employee drags a leave-event into their fullcalendar for 2 days, and the manager approves it, but then decides later that they want to take 3 days off instead, I need a way to visually depict that 2-out-of-3 days is approved within that colored-bar-event in calendar.

You know how MS Outlook/Calendar has that "accepted state" and "non-accepted state" with the little diagonal-grey-lines.  That's what I'm after - - - some visual way of showing that days 1 and 2 of the event are approved and day 3 of the event is not approved.  I have not seen anything in the documentation that provides a "change visual attributes of the bar based on what date it spans over" yet.  Is this even technically possible?

Comment: `If an employee drags a leave-event into their fullcalendar for 2 days, and the manager approves it, but then decides later that they want to take 3 days off instead`...wouldn't they just book one extra day and it would show as a separate event? Most leave systems I've seen work that way, rather than appending to an existing booking (which is what I think you're suggesting).

Comment: I like your suggestion.  Ok, I will do that instead.